# What damage type does the Disintegrate spell deal?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, damage-types

The description of the [*Disintegrate*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=76) spell reads:

> You fire a green ray at your target. Make a spell attack. You deal 12d10 damage, and the target must attempt a basic Fortitude save.

What type of damage is this considered?

The CRB, as far as I can tell, makes no mention of untyped damage. There are untyped penalties and bonuses to checks, but all damage appears to have a type. In fact, determining the damage type is considered a critical step in dealing [damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=335):

> #### Step 2: Determine the Damage Type
>
> Once you’ve calculated how much damage you deal, you’ll need to determine the damage type.

One might assume that this spell deals force damage, as it does in D&D 5th edition. The CRB even specifies that "powerful and pure magical energy can manifest itself as force damage", but other spells that deal force damage such as *Magic Missile* and *Blade Barrier* specify that they deal force damage.

So is the *Disintegrate* spell the sole example of untyped damage in *Pathfinder* 2e? Or is there a precedent somewhere for untyped damage that I haven't seen?

Comment: Green damage, obviously. (I kid, this is a great question, you’ve done some research  and explained what you found).

Comment: thanks! it's also an interesting question for how it interacts with stuff like the resistances of a ghost or wraith, who resist "all but force, ghost touch, or positive" - so Disintegrate being untyped would seem to mean it gets reduced by that resistance, whereas a Magic Missile wouldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Typeless Damage

Nothing in Pathfinder 2e puts the damage dealt by *disintegrate* as force damage, or as any other type of damage. This lack of damage type is repeated across a few spells, including *[implosion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=162)* and *[power word kill](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=227)*, so it doesn't seem to be in error despite not being explicitly described in the list of damage types.

Damage without type would bypass most resistances, as they typically specify a subset of damage types like 'fire' or 'piercing' that typeless damage lacks. As you've mentioned however, an incorporeal creature's resistance to all damage would still apply normally, as typeless damage is still damage.